My .NetFramework version does not work with my Microsoft.SharePointClient.dll version
I am trying to add some CSOM functionality to my C# program such that I will be allowed to do CRUD operations on a Microsoft List (aka SharePoint List).  Assuming you know what CSOM and CRUD is, I will not bore you with the details of the specifics.  The end result of adding the references to the DLLS and the proper namespace, I get an error in my IDE:

"Could not install package 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll
15.0.4420.1017'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2', but the package does not
contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible
with that framework. For more information, contact the package
author."

And so, I have two questions:
What .NetFramework version is compatible  with Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll 15.0.4420.1017 ?
(question 1)
What Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll version is compatible  with .NETFramework Version=v4.7.2 ?
(question 2)

What package did you install? Where did Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll come from? This isn't about .NET Framework versions at all. You're probably trying to install a .NET Core package in .NET Framework. .NET 5 and later are .NET Core, not .NET Framework versions. BTW SharePoint isn't a database and lists aren't tables. If you think of them in terms of CRUD operations you'll run into serious performance problems very quickly

Are you connecting to SharePoint Online or on-premise and what version? SharePoint client libraries have changed a lot over the years and the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client package is 10 years old and way beyond unsupported, unless you use an old on-premise SP version. It's definitely not compatible with .NET Core

For SharePoint online try the Graph APIs and clients. MS has been pushing people to the Graph APIs for half a decade at least. For SharePoint on-prem, you can probably use the Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM package

would you please provide us with an update on the status of your issue?

Have you tried adding it via this nuget package (exact version match from your question).
I have added it without any errors in a Console Application targetting .NET Framework 4.7.2 on Visual Studio 2019.
As it is released around 2013-2014, I'd assume it targets .NET Framework 4 if not .NET Framework 4.5, so it should really work on .NET Framework 4.7.2 without issues.

That's probably what caused the problem. It's a 10 year old package (ie abandoned) that probably only works with old and by now unsupported on-premise versions. It won't work in any .NET Core project. .NET 5 and later are actually .NET Core versions. It won't support calls and features added in the last 10 years either

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client：This NuGet package includes assemblies needed to use the Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Client Object Model for .NET managed applications.
I think you need to install the office.
